# Rails: link_to in button only works in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser

I am using Rails v4.2.5, Ruby v2.3.0p0, and Bootstrap 3. I have two links on the same page, (so they are being served by the same view and controller). One is a button, and another is just a link. Both are created with the link_to function.

Here is the syntax of the links:

```
<div class="logIn">
    <strong><%= link_to "LOG IN", login_path, :class =>"linkys" %></strong>
</div>
```

And here is the second link:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
    <%= link_to "GO!", search_url %>
</button>
```

The second link does not work in any browser except Chrome. The first link works perfectly.

Comment: You might want to check the HTML standard to see what it says about [`<a>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html) and [`<button>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.button.html). Neither `<button><a href="...">...</a></button>` nor `<a href="..."><button>...</button></a>` are valid HTML which actually makes a lot of sense since they're both clickable elements.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that. I'm not sure what html is generated by the link_to I posted as an answer, but I'll see if I can find that out.

Comment: A simple `link_to name, url` should give you `<a href="url">name</a>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap button links in Rails should be made with the following syntax:

```
<%= link_to "GO!", search_url, :class => "btn btn-default" %>
```

In fact, to change the class of any link, you should use the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Update this part:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
    <%= link_to "GO!", search_url %>
</button>
```

**To** (change the class of your choice):

```
<%= link_to "GO!", search_url, class: "btn btn-warning btn-large" %>
```

**Equivalent to**:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-large" href="/search_url">GO!</a>
```